# Flex accesibility requirement

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, accessibility, flash-builder, mxml

How to add accessibility requirements to a swf created using mxml+flex sdk? I have a few buttons and textfields in the swf and the impaired user should be able to increase the button size and text size while using the swf. I've looked into [flex built-in accessibility](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/best_practices.html) features, but its not what I require. 
I want to run the swf standalone without a browser, so preferably change the size with a visual widget.

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy posted a good solution so that the user can use Ctrl +/- to increase all 
font sizes in a Flex app.

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Change_font_size_in_the_whole_app_with_Ctrl___-16307.html

Comment: thanks. what about a standalone or air app? also, where is the full code(with mxml+as3) for http://kachurovskiy.com/f/ria/09/fontSize/FontSizeChange.html ?